# 3D Scatter Plot with Plotly in R without lines

Tags: r, plot, plotly, scatter3d

I've been struggling with this for a while. I know I can turn off most hover functionality by including hoverinfo = 'none', but I still see the lines that connect to the 3 axes when plotting a 3D Scatter Plot. Is there a way to turn off that functionality? I included a picture that hopefully makes clear what lines I'm trying to get rid off.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by including showspikes = FALSE in the layout. I should read documentation more carefully. I am an idiot!